# Please assist me with this simple script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementsbytagname

I am new to JavaScript and would like to ask for some help with my simple script.

What I am trying to do is to retrieve and display the values of all list item elements in the unordered list with the help of the (for) loop. I was able to get the script display all list items in the alert window one by one. But the problem is that I need values of all list elements displayed in a table row way. Like this:

Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
.......

Here is what I have in my script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
    function process() {
        a = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            alert(a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
    }
//-->
</script>
```

And here is HTML code:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Monday</li>
        <li>Tuesday</li>
        <li>Wednesday</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="process()" />
</body>
```

If that's possible at all would anyone please also explain where I am wrong in my script? Why all 3 list item values can't be shown in the alert window at once?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am unable to assist without example code.

Comment: Do you want a table row going across or column like how you list? What does it parse out right now?

Comment: @Kris the question was formatted incorrectly; code is now visible.

Comment: Save the result concatenating through the loop all the values in a single VAR, then outside the "for loop", write the contents of the VAR, there will be all your unordered list.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a string variable: `var all_at_once = ""`. Then, add the contents of the `nodeValue`. Finally, alert this variable:

```
function process(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
    var all_at_once = "";
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        all_at_once += a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
    }
    alert(all_at_once);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `alert` shows repeatedly because that is what a `for` loop does... it loops! The loop will iterate over the array of elements returned by `getElementsByTagName`, executing the loop body once for each element in that array.

If you wanted to display one alert, an option would be to build up a string containing the appropriate text, and `alert` it afterwards:

```
var yourString = "";
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    yourString += a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
alert(yourString);
```

Some other notes on your code... you should almost always declare variables with the `var` keyword to prevent them leaking into the global scope. You should also always end lines with semi-colons:

```
function process(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
        yourString = "";
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        yourString += a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    alert(yourString);
}
```

Comment: All of your answers are fantastic!

Thanks a lot for helping me to resolve this issue! I was about to put up the idea of learning javascript any longer:) I will try some more now

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

    function process(){
        var data = '';
        a=document.getElementsByTagName('li')

            for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){

                    data = data  + '\n' +(a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
         alert(data);
    }


//-->
</script>
```

You need to call alert only once if you need 1 popup with all the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
function process()
{
  var a = getElementsByTagName('li'),
      text = '';

  for( i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
  {
    text += a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '\n';
  }

  alert( text );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the days in whatever manner you like by storing them in an array first, and then iterating:

```
var days = new Array();
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    days.push(a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}

for (i=0; i < days.length; i++) {
    // process the day
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/Cfg4k/ for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

These few adjustments to your function should produce the result you want. Good luck!
What changed: 1) Set up an empty string var 2) Instead of alerting each value, just append them to the string var you created earlier 3) Finally, alert the newly created (concatenated) string!

```
function process() {
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var days = new String("");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        days = days+(a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)+"\n";
    }
    alert(days);
}
```

Now I see there have been tons of answers since opening this thread... but maybe all the different solutions will help you in different ways.